# Cleanup SHA tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that:

- Tags [sha2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha2) and [sha256](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha256) should be merged to [sha-2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha-2). In my opinion having special tag for SHA-256 doesn't actually make sense.
- [sha](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha) should be renamed to [sha-1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha-1) as we don't curretly have questions talking about SHA as about family of hashing algorithms. All of them refer to specific versions.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, since this is a *security* site, and I expect almost any algorithm-specific question to be on the [Cryptography](http://cryptography.stackexchange.com) site instead of here, I personally think we shouldn't even have any algorithm-specific tags, *at all*.

Rather, I would instead of both [sha2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha2) and [sha256](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha256), I would retag them both as [hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash); I would do the same for [sha](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha) and [sha-1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sha-1). Same with [md5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/md5).

I would do the same for encryption algorithms, too - e.g. instead of [aes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes) and [3des](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3des) simply have [encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption), or possibly [symmetric-encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetric-encryption).

My point is, most of those questions either: (a) should be asked on crypto, because it is about the algorithm details; or (b) mostly irrelevant which algorithm is used, from a security management point of view; or (c) apply to a range of algorithms, or the specific algorithm is not known in the question (e.g. which algorithm to use in a specific situation).

Comment: Algorthmic tags may exist as there are questions about how to correctly use those algorithms. Usage of crypto is a topic of security.SE. Crypto internals is a topic of crypto.SE

Comment: I do understand where AviD is coming from. Looking through the various questions tagged as [tag:sha] or [tag:sha256], they all can fit into the [tag:hash] tag.

Comment: And considering the low volume of questions tagged with that compared to the generic [tag:hash] tag, AviD's solution makes sense.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov "Usage of crypto" would most often be irrelevant of the algorithm. "When should I use symmetric encryption", it doesnt matter if you're using AES or DES; "How can I ensure my signature is valid for the correct public key" is irrelevant of RSA, DSA, or anything else; "How should we do key management" only matters if it is symmetric or asymmetric. And so on.

Comment: Think of it this way: Crypto is a tool. In a professional's toolbox, there are many similar tools; if you want to ask specifics about the tools, there is a site for that. Just because we have many different heads for our drill, we dont need to tag [tag:eighth-inch-drillbit] separately from [tag:three-and-half-inch-drillbit]; or [tag:flathead-screwdriver] from [tag:philipshead-screwdriver] - using the tools would be the same either way.

Comment: +1 on this. Hash is the best option.